# Raspberry Pi - run a program with specified internet connection

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, openvpn

Is it possible without virtual machines to do the following on RPi (raspbian image) via console only?

I'll have 5 open vpn connections. I have a program that will be started in 5 instances too. Can I specify somehow what connection should each instance use? First of all I thought about 'screen' command, but I think that I'll have no luck.

The program is a client, which connects to a server with specified IP:port and sending USB hardware parameters.

For example:

```
openvpn --config "1"
start1.sh
openvpn --config "2"
start2.sh
...
openvpn --config "5"
start5.sh
```

I would like to have something like this. But I think that every started process will use only last established connection.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that I should use network namespaces. Here are the links, that may be helpfull to visitors of this question. I didn't find another ways how to do it.

[link one](http://lwn.net/Articles/580893/)

[link two](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/04/introducing-linux-network-namespaces/)

[link three](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149293/feed-all-traffic-through-openvpn-for-a-specific-network-namespace-only)